# How to make a download link in GitHub README.md file?

Tags: github

I uploaded a `.epub` file to the GitHub repository. I want to create a download link to this file inside the README.md file.

By clicking this link user will be able to download the file directly, without going to another page and clicking the download button on that page.

Is it possible to achieve this with the default README.md (markdown) file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ***text*** comes e.g. "click me" and at ***link*** just your downloadlink

You can do it with this:

```
[text](link)
```

as an example:

```
[click me to download](https://github.com/Schecher1/Minecraft-Server-Creator/blob/master/README.md)
```

Comment: It looks like the target file should be uploaded to the release assets and linked inside the readme file. In other cases, when, for example, the link points to a file that is stored inside the repository's source files, it does not work.

Comment: Yes, you can. Or take the perma link of the file (you get top right by the dots)

Comment: You can use any file-link. You are not allowed to take e.g. the page. but it must be the link to the file. It can be that you have accidentally taken the wrong link.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the download link by putting my `.epub` file inside a release assets.

After creating a release I right-clicked on the artifact and copied the link address.

The markdown snippet looks like this

```
[epub](https://github.com/name/project/releases/download/v1.0.0/book.epub)
```

It immediately starts loading the file upon clicking the `epub` word.